# Do Node net.Socket.on("data") events have a guaranteed order?

Tags: node.js, sockets, networking, tcp

I am creating a socket in Node.js with `net.connect(host, port)`, writing some data to it, and then listening for the results back on the socket.

The TCP protocol has ordering information built into it; packets can be sent or arrive out of order and then rearranged by the client, by using information built into the packet metadata.

Node.js fires a series of `.on("data")` events to let you know that data has been received on the socket. These events are fired in some order - there is only one thread of execution so they cannot be processed simultaneously.

Is the order of fired data events guaranteed to be the TCP packet order? Is it possible for the `.on("data")` events to fire out of order, for data received on a socket?

Answer (score 1):

TCP data is delivered by the OS to the TCP socket in-order or not at all. AFAIK NodeJS basically does an `epoll()` (via libuv) on the open sockets and reads data when it arrives. It then queues a `data` event, which is delivered to our event handler in-order.

So I do not think it is possible form `data` events for a socket to be handled out-of-order. If that were possible, it would be very hard to handle TCP traffic reliably in NodeJS.

Comment: If the server sends 5k of data and TCP decides to split that buffer and only sends a partial buffer to the client e.g. 1k, does net hold the 1k of data till the remining chunks arrive and then present a single  'on data' event only when the complete 5k buffer has arrived? Or will multiple 'on data' events be fired for each chunk. In which case, how does the client know when all the chunks have arrived without knowing rhe original size to expect?

Comment: TCP is a stream-based protocol and has no concept of discrete messages. If you need to send discrete messages over a TCP connection you have to implement some kind of "framing" in the application protocol to separate messages. You can do this, for example, by prepending a length to each message or by appending a delimiter. Application messages can be split over multiple `data` events **and** there can be multiple messages within a single `data` event.